# is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.8

So im scraping links using selenium.  I can print my links with my loop but I cant navigate to them because I get the following error:

***selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed***

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.famousgraphicdesigners.org/")

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="pages-2"]/div/ul/li/a')
links_total = len(links)
print("Found", links_total, "total links.\n")

for i in links:
    # print(i.get_attribute('href')) # This works
    driver.get(i.get_attribute('href')) # This doesnt work

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 12):

When you navigate to a new page the previously located elements become stale, in that case the elements in `links`, so you can't access the `href` attribute. Kee p all the `href`s in a list of strings and iterate over it

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="pages-2"]/div/ul/li/a')
links_hrefs = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]

for i in links_hrefs:
    driver.get(i)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didnt know that I lost the elements once i left the page.

Answer (score 2):

I came across same problem and
"browser.refresh()"
before calling same element solved my issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this is because the element to which you have referred is removed from the DOM structure.

**solution** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

links = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.famousgraphicdesigners.org/')

all_Links = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='pages-2']/div/ul/li/a[@href]")))

for link in all_Links:
    print link.get_attribute("href")
    links.append(link.get_attribute("href"))

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
```

Comment: The OP want to navigate, not print. Using `WebDriverWait` won't solve the issue.